# Regular expression to match any table tag

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to see if a string contains any of the typical table tags:

```
<table></table>
<td></td>
<th></th>
<tr></tr>
<thead></thead>
<tfoot></tfoot>
<tbody></tbody>
```

Along with tags that may contain other attributes e.g:

```
<table border="1">
```

I've come up with this so far, however, it matches `<br />` tag and I'm not sure why:

```
/<\/?[table|td|th|tr|tfoot|thead|tbody]{1,}>?/
```

http://www.rexfiddle.net/20Xtqka

Comment: It's matching br because of the square brackets and the "tr". You are just saying, match at least one of these characters with the square brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions use parentheses, not square brackets, to group things. A set of characters inside square brackets matches any of those characters.

```
/<\/?(table|td|th|tr|tfoot|thead|tbody)+>?/
```

When you want to match 1 or more of something, use `+` rather than `{1,}`.

Comment: The basic concept of using regular expressions to parse HTML is flawed. Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/127145). Thanks!

Comment: That should be a comment on the original question, not my answer.